# Testing my Sheets Workspace Add-on will Install but will not "run" onOpen in a new test sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

Here is my expected and actual breakdown, based on my reading of the various Google Developer documentation for building a Google Sheets Editor and Workspace Add-on

**Expected** outcome: After navigating to Deploy -> Test Deployments -> Workspace Add-ons and clicking Install, then upon clicking done, I open a new spreadsheet ("sheet.new") and upon opening the document and waiting a few seconds, I expect that my Add-on's custom menu item will display in the `Extensions` drop down menu

The Test deployment section for deploying a "test Workspace Add-on"
[image]

**Actual** outcome: After navigating to Deploy -> Test Deployments -> Workspace Add-ons and clicking Install, then upon clicking **done**, I open a new spreadsheet ("sheet.new") and upon opening and waiting a few seconds, there is no custom menu item displaying in the `Extensions` drop down menu (or in any other menu of course). And there is no reference to any other `onOpen(e)` event for this new sheet in my Cloud Logs.

For context, this Google Sheets add-on is fairly simple - it has two custom functions that make external API requests, and an HTML "settings" sidebar where users can quickly reference some links and admin read-only fields.

*Edit*: and confirming that the Add-on *does* work as expected in the Test Deployment modes for Enabled, Installed & Enabled `authMode`s, it's just in the last mile of testing where I am trying to get the host-application (Sheets in this case) to be extended that I am encountering this issue.

I have read just about every other related stackoverflow post, but none of the answers are either relevant or address my extension's use-case.

I am not sure if there's something missing from `appsscript.json`/manifest file, or there's something silently blocking the installation, here's my current 'anonymized' manifest file:

```json
{
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "My sheets app",
      "logoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/__PIC_ID__",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#B8136C"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onOpen"
      }
    }
  },
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "serviceId": "sheets",
        "version": "v4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "openid",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://www.mysamplesite.net/"
  ],
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

Is there anything immediately obviously wrong with the appsscript.json properties, or any other other troubleshooting steps I should take?

EDIT: I also for fun tried several permutations of editing, including changing the `appsscript.json` homepageTrigger properties to this:

```json
"sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "addMenu"
      }
```

The `addMenu` function is a function in my code.gs file that adds a custom menu item to the Extensions menu. After saving my changes, uninstalling (clicking Done) and reinstalling (clicking Done) this did **not** seem to have the expected (and desired) impact I was looking for.

EDIT 2: Uploading this test of the `View document add-ons` approach that @AlejandroTalamet suggested
[image]

Comment: Addons are independent scripts. They don't have any relations/connetctions with any types of documents in Google Drive. Hence, they don't trigger events such as OnOpen, OnEdit, onSubmit, etc.

Comment: @gorkhali1234 I am not sure I understand the implication of what you are suggesting. Are you saying `sheets.homepageTrigger.runFunction: { "onOpen" }` is incorrect? What should I do instead to fix it? this aspect of manifest file structure is incredibly ambiguous in google's docs

Comment: Also, I believe the whole point of the testing is to mount the script (+html and .json manifest files) as an Add-on for the "host application" in this case Google sheets @gorkhali1234

Comment: @alejandrotamalet do you think you could take a look please? 

Comment: My bad, I thought this was a workspace addon. Anyway there's a warning in docs for the onOpen in editor addon:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#opening

Comment: I mean, @gorkhali1234 it's both an Editor Add-On *and* a Workspace Add-On? It's an editor Add-On intended to be published in the Workspace Marketplace. I'm not sure if that changes anything

Comment: Workspace add-on can't trigger events like onEdit, onOpen, etc. You can't add a UI menu to the spreadsheets from an independent script, at least in the case of Workspace Addon its not possible.

Comment: if that's true then what is the point of testing the Workspace Add-on?

Comment: Editor add-ons are not automatically enabled in new documents. If you install an add-on while in a  doc/spreadsheet it will be enabled there, but in others you have to Extesnsions -> Add-ons -> View document add-ons and enable it.

Comment: thanks @AlejandroTamalet, however just now after I confirmed that my `Latest Code` Add-On is still installed, however when I go to a new Google Sheets document, my `View Document Add Ons` menu option is disabled/greyed out. I appended a screenshot in my main Question to as a visual context